# is it possible to iterate through two arrays for matching values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase databse is as follows:

```
Users {
    askdfasdf: John: {
            Selection: [1,2,3]
                     },
    fasfadffe: Mark: {
   Selection: [1,2,4]
                    } 
     }

Players {
{
name: 'Messi',
agility: 90,
id: 1
},
{
name: 'Beckham',
agility: 54,
id: 2
},
{
name: 'Rooney',
agility: 10,
id: 3
},
{
name: 'Neymar',
agility: 84,
id: 4
}
}
```

The database nodes are brought into the scope by the following code:

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("players");
  var ref3 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).child("total");

  $scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.selection = $firebaseArray(ref3);
```

Is there a way to itereate or loop through two arrays in search of matching values? Specifically, is there a way to loop through the "players" array in search of the players whose `id`s match the numbers in the "selection" array.

The ultimate goal is to have each client's selections reflected on the page after their selection has been made.

My databse security rules are as follows:

```
{
 "rules": {
"players":{
  ".read" : "auth != null",
  ".write" : "auth != null",
    ".indexOn": "id"
  }
  } 
}
```

I have tried iterating over each selection as follows:

```
$scope.getSelectedPlayers = function (){
for (let i = 0; i<$scope.selection.length; i++){
    return $scope.selection[i];

 var ref= 
  firebase.database().ref("players").orderByChild("id").equalTo($scope.selection[i]);
}
```

but this did not work

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry could you elaborate on that? I'm not quite sure what that means?

Comment: sorry, it was just thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object with `id` as keys for the single players.

With iterating `users`, you could add the wanted information by taking the `id` for an access to the player information.

```js
var players = [{ name: 'Messi', agility: 90, id: 1 }, { name: 'Beckham', agility: 54, id: 2 }, { name: 'Rooney', agility: 10, id: 3 }, { name: 'Neymar', agility: 84, id: 4 }],
    object = Object.create(null);

players.forEach(p => object[p.id] = p);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You could query each selected id using `equalTo`, keep in mind you have to index Player.id in the firebase security rules.

Then simply:

```
firebase.database().ref("players").orderByChild("id").equalTo('selected_id_here');
```

You can find more in firebase docs: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: thanks but I'm not quite sure how to index Player.id in the security rules. The article was quite confusing. Sorry if this is a silly question but could i possibly see how that can be done?

Comment: Check it out here: [indexing-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

Comment: thanks. Yeah i read that and was quite confused. I have edited my question to reflect what my rules are now. Is this correct syntax?

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly when I replaced 'selected_id_here' with aactual numbers. However, given that the user selection is a 6 number array dependent on each client's selections, is there a way to iterate over each selection to get each player with the corresponding id to be shown? The code i have tried is shown in my edited question

Comment: this is mainly because the slelected ids which will occupy the 'selected_id-here' part of the db reference in your answer will be completely different with each client. Furthermore, as it stands, the selcted id aare in the array called $scpe.selected